# Adding leading and trailing zeros in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I add leading zeros using geometry nodes?

Example snippet:  I have a counter that animates values in degrees 0-360 and converts the values into strings.

[image: img1]

I would like the numbers to have at least **3 places in front and 1 place after the decimal**.

Example: **the number 1 would be 001.0 and 20 would be 020.0**

Comment: There's a recent video by Joey Carlino [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcNWOPVAZsk) showing how to construct a timer string with a leading zero and delimiter characters using geometry nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this node setup here:

[image]